# Ruby Installation issues with rvm after Ubuntu New updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am on the way to install rails. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LLTS

> vipin@vipin-Satellite-C640:~$ uname -a
>   Linux 3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

First I followed [this](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).

but when i tried

> rails -v

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I reinstall ruby by

> vipin@vipin-Satellite-C640:~$ rvm reinstall 2.1.0

Now I tried

> ruby -v

again same result

```
vipin@vipin-Satellite-C640:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I tried to uninstall rvm

```
vipin@vipin-Satellite-C640:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
[sudo] password for vipin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ruby-rvm is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

UPDATE :
I was able to successfully created apps with rails in Ubuntu. Now I updated and upgraded the Kernel.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what does `rvm list` produce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken version of RVM. Ubuntu does something to RVM that produces lots of errors, the only safe way of fixing for now is to:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ruby-rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

open new terminal and validate environment is clean from old RVM settings (should be no output):

```
env | grep rvm
```

if there was output, try to open new terminal, if it does not help then restart your computer.

[install RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/):

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | 
  bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

If you find you need some hand-holding, take a look at [Installing Ruby on Ubuntu 12.04](http://blog.coolaj86.com/articles/installing-ruby-on-ubuntu-12-04.html), which gives a bit more explanation.

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm` is for removing the whole thing. `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ruby-rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` is for deleting any remaining files then reinstall according to the liks provided by me. http://blog.coolaj86.com/articles/installing-ruby-on-ubuntu-12-04.html

Comment: I got this   `~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm`  
`[sudo] password for vipin:`   
`Reading package lists... Done`  
`Building dependency tree`         
`Reading state information... Done`  
`Package ruby-rvm is not installed, so not removed`  
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: no prob man  go forward and do rest of the instructions given in my answer